# ExpressJS and Angular - 'leaving' the app to do server-side authentication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js

My app runs on NodeJS, ExpressJS and AngularJS. I'm trying to do Facebook authentication using PassportJS. To avoid posting a bunch of unnecessary code, let's just say that the Passport code works as intended and logs into Facebook, grabs the token and receives a response.

In ExpressJS my routes are set up as follows:

```
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/fbauth', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: 'email' }));
app.get('/fbauthed', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ failureRedirect: '/' }), routes.loggedin);
app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  req.logOut();
  res.redirect('/');
});
```

My server is set up at `localhost:3000`.

**Question**

My issue is that Angular is not behaving with this at all. When I put a link on my page which goes to `href="/fbauth"` (this goes to `localhost:3000/fbauth`) I see the address bar change to `localhost:3000/fbauth` for a split second, then my main `localhost:3000` page reloads.

However, if I type `localhost:3000/fbauth` into the address bar, the authentication happens and I'm passed along to facebook -> `localhost:3000/fbauthed`.

I ***think*** this is happening because Angular routes are trying to 'take over' the URL in the `<a>` link, but I have no idea how to achieve it. I've tried configuring my Angular routes to:

```
when('/fbauth', {
        redirectTo: '/fbauth'
      }).
```

But this loads a blank screen. How can I make the two work together?

Comment: Look at 'HTML link rewriting' section in documentation of `$location` service http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location. It has precisely details on how to stop Angular from overriding the urls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding target="_self" works in Angular 1.0.1:

Sign in with Facebook

This feature is documented (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location - search for '_self')

If you're curious, look at the angular source (line 5365 @ v1.0.1). The click hijacking only happens if !elm.attr('target') is true.

Comment: One issue - I start inside the app, then do the authentication, which leaves the app. How do I get back 'inside' the app? As above, I'm currently taken to `/fbauthed`, but this is obviously outside of any controllers...

Comment: You should setup route for angular when /fbauthed where point to controller

Comment: Got it working, had to change the above code in my node/express app to `app.get('/fbauthed', passport.authenticate('facebook',{ failureRedirect: '/' }), <INSERT ANGULAR ROUTE HERE>);`